# Can't use Monogame.Framework.Graphics

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna, nuget, monogame

I'm porting my XNA game to Mono.  I've installed the Monogame Windows NuGet package and ran the installer provided at monogame.net, but I still don't have access to the majority of the Monogame framework, like Monogame.Framework.Graphics, Vector2, etc.  Why not?

Edit: I can even see it referenced in Visual Studio.  It's the right version and everything.  What is going on?

[image: ReferenceManager]

[image: Intellisense]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NuGet package is just the Visual Studio templates for MonoGame. You need to install the actual framework.

Download from their website: http://www.monogame.net

Once installed, your code will build just fine. To maintain compatibility with XNA projects, Monogame uses XNA namespaces (but does not require XNA DNA to work). See community discussion here: http://community.monogame.net/t/solved-xna-no-longer-required-to-use-monogame/2803/3

Comment: I forgot to mention, but I did this.  Installed it and ... is there another step?

Comment: @GameKyuubi Your code should build. MonoGame uses XNA namespaces. See discussion here: https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/issues/3306

Comment: @GameKyuubi I updated my answer with a link to community discussion as to why Microsoft.XNA namespaces were kept. Sorry, I presumed your project didn't build, as your OP did not specify you already installed the framework. Your project should build, even though XNA libraries are not referenced (namespace can be anything, and is not 100% indicative of assembly vendor  - you can create own dll that is Microsoft.XNA.something...)

Comment: Ok cool.  So just to be 100% clear, the namespace says XNA, but is actually MonoGame.  Thanks!